# debugging code in eclipse, issues with testing code

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started to use Eclipse and I am having issues with testing my code. It seems that every time I want to debug a piece of code I need to do a maven clean and install, and then refresh for the changes to propagate. This process takes around 5 minutes, which is extremely troublesome (if i want to change a line of code, i need to wait 5 minutes .. and then test it). Is there a way to bypass this, perhaps modify the jar files directly or is there an option/plugin in eclipse to help with this?.

I know there a auto build option but it doesnt seem to do anything .. or am i missing something?

Comment: What kind of project is it? Is the maven nature for the project installed? Are all files from the project saved? is `Project -> Build Automatically` ticked? Does the project build without errors? What do you mean by "modify jar files", a normal run should only create .class files in `target/classes/`. Are there .class files?

Comment: What happens when you clean the project `Project -> Clean` and try to run it afterwards? Is this Project a dependency from a different project? `mvn install` can cause problems in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the m2e plugin to manage how eclipse integrates with maven.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Integration

> - Dependency management for Eclipse build path based on Maven's pom.xml
> - Resolving Maven dependencies from the Eclipse workspace without    installing to local Maven repository

You can download it here: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/